# CakePHP 2.4 how to verify user? (No PASSWORD)

Tags: cakephp, authorization

in cakePHP 2.4 > is new process of user authentication.

In db table and model i got password columns named as "passwd", form input is named same as db column.

**So in User model i have:**

```
if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['passwd'])) {
   $passwordHasher = new SimplePasswordHasher();
   $this->data[$this->alias]['passwd'] = $passwordHasher->hash($this->data[$this->alias]['passwd']);
                }
```

**In User Controller i got**

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    // Allow users to register and logout.
    $this->Auth->allow('register','verify','login');
    $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
        'Form' => array(
            'fields' => array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'passwd'),
        ),
    );
}


public function login() {
    // accept only ajax post request
    if ($this->request->is('ajax') && $this->request->is('post')) {

        $tmpUser['User']['username'] = $this->request->data['User']['email'];
        $tmpUser['User']['password'] = $this->request->data['User']['passwd'];

        // try to login user
        if ($this->Auth->login ($tmpUser)) {
            echo('Login Successfull');
        } else {
            echo('Login Incorrect');
        }
    }
}
```

But unfortunately i still cannot successfully log in. In SQL dump is not available posted password (only username).

I tried to find some helpful information but nothing from found was working.

So i tried documentation on:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html

But still without luck.

Is here anybody with same problem or somebody who have a solution for this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `$this->Auth->login ($tmpUser)` => you are number 14433 who doesnt understand the difference between () and ($var). You are not trying to login, you are always logging the person in. See the documentation. There is even a warning about that difference.

Comment: Do You think this?
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in

Comment: Also add the view code including the JS where you AJAX POST the data. There most likely is your problem that you need to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Why remapping?
That will not work

```
if ($this->request->is('ajax') && $this->request->is('post')) {

    // expects this to be posted:
    // $this->request->data['User']['email'];
    // $this->request->data['User']['passwd'];

    // try to login user
    if ($this->Auth->login()) {}
```

Comment: No, this is not working for me, it just checks user email instead of the user email and password.

Comment: Did you verify that the expected data is posted in the expected format? Using debug(), or logging or whatever?

Comment: Yes, is it AJAX POST call (jQuery serialized form data) to method login on controller User.

Comment: I am not talking about the frontend, nor the way you transport it. Of course its AJAX and POST. I asked if you verified it on the receiving end - inside the login action prio to calling login(). There is your issue. I bet the incoming data is not in the expected format. There you need to correct your code or write a custom Auth adapter.

Comment: Could You please add some working example? I tried Form, Basic and Digest authentication and i red whole Authentication chapter on CakePHP doc but still without luck.